# Include empty directory with python setup.py sdist

Tags: python, installation

I have a Python package where I want to include an empty directory as part of the source distribution. I tried adding

```
include empty_directory
```

to the `MANIFEST.in` file, but when I run

```
python setup.py sdist
```

The empty directory is still not included. Any tips on how to do this?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

According to [the docs](http://docs.python.org/distutils/commandref.html#sdist-cmd):

> - `include pat1 pat2` - *include all
>     files matching any of the listed
>     patterns*
> - `exclude pat1 pat2` -
>     *exclude all files matching any of the listed patterns*
> - `recursive-include dir pat1 pat2` - *include all files
>     under dir matching any of the listed
>     patterns*
> - `recursive-exclude dir pat1 pat2` - *exclude all files under
>     dir matching any of the listed
>     patterns*
> - `global-include pat1 pat2` - *include all files anywhere in
>     the source tree matching — & any of
>     the listed patterns*
> - `global-exclude pat1 pat2` - *exclude
>     all files anywhere in the source tree
>     matching — & any of the listed
>     patterns*
> - `prune dir` - *exclude
>     all files under dir*
> - `graft dir` -
>     *include all files under dir*

So seems like you want `graft`, not `include`.
Also, it seems you can't include empty directories. You have to create a "`empty.txt`" file or something like this inside the directory to force its inclusion.

Comment: This seems to be a common practice with many dist systems. I've seen something like "empty.txt" or DELETE included with a simple note saying "This may be deleted at any time.".